# Test if a range intersects another range of numbers

Tags: php, numbers, range, pseudocode

I have  2 range of numbers:

- `$startTime` to `$endTime`
- `$offerStartTime` to `$offerEndTime`

Each of the above variables are integers.

I want to see if the range `offerStartTime` to `offerEndTime` falls in the range `startTime` and `endTime`.

For example, if the `startTime` and `endTime` range was: 10 to 20, then the following example ranges would return `true`:

- `offerStartTime: 5, offerEndTime: 11`
- `offerStartTime: 5, offerEndTime: 100`
- `offerStartTime: 10, offerEndTime: 15`
- `offerStartTime: 10, offerEndTime: 100`
- `offerStartTime: 12, offerEndTime: 15`
- `offerStartTime: 19, offerEndTime: 100`

The following would return `false`:

- `offerStartTime: 1, offerEndTime: 3`
- `offerStartTime: 90, offerEndTime: 100`
- `offerStartTime: 1, offerEndTime: 10`
- `offerStartTime: 20, offerEndTime: 100`

How can I do this?
Would ideally like answers in PHP, but pseudo code would be fine.

Comment: Are you dealing with unix timestamps? if so, you should use the `DateTime` class

Comment: Its actually number of seconds into the day. i.e. 0 to 86400

Comment: Run a loop in a function that takes in start,end times,offerstart,offerend, loop from start time to end end, adding up until start >= end and test if offerstart/offerend are within one of the loops

Comment: How does `5` fall in between `10` and `20`? And `100`?

Comment: @AbraCadaver `5` is the `offerStartTime`  the `offerEndTime` is `11`. The range between both numbers fall into the range of `10` to `20`, specifically `10` and `11`.

Comment: @YahyaUddin I think based on your inputs/expected outputs, you are looking for range intersection, but in my opinion "falls in the range" sounds like one range should be entirely contained within the other (both endpoints). Can you clarify?

Comment: I think "range intersection" would be a better wording.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are just checking whether any part of the offer overlaps any part of the range, it's simple.

```
if ($offerStartTime < $endTime && $offerEndTime > $startTime)  {
    echo 'The ranges overlap';
}
```

Here's a picture representing all the possibilities of overlap and non-overlap to visualize why this works.

[image]

Based on your inputs and expected false outputs, I used `<` and `>`. If you wanted to also include ranges that intersected at a point, you would need to use `<=` and `>=` instead.

Comment: You know I think you might be right. After all those complex answers lol. Let me wait for a bit to see if there are any cases where this does not work before upvoting this.

Comment: This works out for my test cases (overlapping, under lapping, and separated ahead and behind)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `range` and `array_intersect`, i.e.:

```
function time_intersect($startTime, $endTime, $offerStartTime, $offerEndTime)
{
    $start_to_end = range($startTime, $endTime, 1);
    $offer_start_end = range($offerStartTime, $offerEndTime, 1);
    if (!empty(array_intersect($start_to_end, $offer_start_end)))
    {
      # time overlaps
      return true;
    }
}
```

---

Explanation:

With `range` we create **2** `arrays` containing numbers based on the **4** variables (start, end), then we use `array_intersect` to check if the 2 arrays have numbers in common, if the output is **not** empty, we know the numbers (time) overlap.

Answer (score 1):

```
//$startTime to $endTime
//$offerStartTime to $offerEndTime
//you can compare php times by using normal comparators so this is just a logic problem. here's the solution.


//ok let's start by making sure that neither offered time is within the range because if it is we KNOW it's already good so

if(($offerStartTime < $endTime && offerStartTime > $startTime) || ($offerEndTime < $endTime && offerEndTime > $startTime)){
      return true;
 }
 //so it's not easily already within the range so we have to test if the lower one is under the starting one but the other is above. ie.
elseif(($offerStartTime < $startTime) && ($offerEndTime > $startTime)){
     return true; 
}
//so the only other acceptable possibility is that the offered start time is lower than the endtime and the offered end time is higher ie
elseif(($offerStartTime < $endTime) && ($offerEndTime > $endTime)){
      return true;
}
//so we've exhausted all other valid possibilities it must be false
else{
      return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help you out, I have tried this with all your inputs and it is working fine..

```
<?php

ini_set('display_errors', 1);

$startTime=10;
$endTime=20;

$startOffset=100;
$endOffset=110;

$range=range($startTime,$endTime);//getting range of time

$offsetRange=range($startOffset,$endOffset);//getting range of offset


$set=array_intersect($range, $offsetRange);//getting the intersection

if(is_array($set) && count($set)>0);
{
    if(count($set)>1)
    {
        echo "Matched";
    }
    //added this to prevent this case offerStartTime: 1, offerEndTime: 10, 
    //ranges intersection is the endTime
    elseif(count($set)==1)
    {
        if($set[0]!=$startTime)
        {
            echo "Matched";
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to test if the start of your smaller range is greater or equal to your larger range's start AND if your end of your smaller range is less than or equal to the end of your larger range:

In this case 10-20 falls within 5-25, so returns true.  If you don't want to include the endpoints of the range simply change `<=` and `>=` to `<` and `>` respectively.

```
<?php

$innerRange = ['start' => 10, 'end' => 20];
$outerRange = ['start' => 5, 'end' => 25];

echo isInRange($innerRange,$outerRange);

function isInRange($innerRange,$outerRange) {
    if ($innerRange['start'] >= $outerRange['start'] && $innerRange['end'] <= $outerRange['end'] ) {
         return true;   
    }
    return false;
}

?>
```

Comment: Your code will not work with `$outerRange = ['start' => 15, 'end' => 25];` for example, so it's not a solution

Answer (score 0):

After some time I have found an efficient simple solution that seems to work (feel free to tell me if it doesn't).

```
($offerStartTime <= $startTime && $offerEndTime > $startTime) ||
($offerStartTime > $startTime && $offerStartTime < $endTime)
```

I will also be looking at answers that are better than mine, so please still send me your solution.