# PHP check int range in other int range

Tags: php

Lets say we have a car with a price of 1000$ to 5000$. Now when user search for a car that starts:

1. from 999$ to 1001$
2. from 1001$ to 4999$
3. from $4999 to $5001

this car should be shown.
So far I have no success.
Tried:

```
$rangeMin = (int)$searchedTerms->rangemin;
    //substract 10% from min range
    $rangeMin = (int)($rangeMin - ($rangeMin / 10));

    $rangeMax = (int)$searchedTerms->rangemax;
    //add 10% to max range
    $rangeMax = (int)($rangeMax + ($rangeMax / 10));

    for($i=0; $i< count($result); $i++){
        if( 
        in_array( (int)$result[$i]['price_min'], range($rangeMin, $rangeMax,1)) || 
        in_array( (int)$result[$i]['price_max'], range($rangeMin, $rangeMax,1) ) || 
        in_array( $rangeMin, range((int)$result[$i]['price_min'], (int)$result[$i]['price_max']),1 ) || 
        in_array( $rangeMax, range((int)$result[$i]['price_min'], (int)$result[$i]['price_max']),1 ) ) {
            array_push($final, $result[$i]);
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is your code doing right now? Any errors in the log? What does result contain? (`var_export($result);` and update your question.) It seems like you'd be passing in your min/max when you build the db query.

Comment: Creating huge arrays for this using `range` is rather nonsense. You have the lower boundary, you have the upper boundary of each price bracket - and that is all you need to check against (greater than/lesser than, maybe including equal), not every single value in between for an exact match.

Comment: Sounds like a job for the database. Assume `$result` comes from one? I'd refine the query that gives the result.

Comment: [I answered a question about something like this a while ago.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43616157/test-if-a-range-intersects-another-range-of-numbers)

Answer (score 0):

A simple if statement should work:

```
return
    ($search['low'] >= $car['low'] && $search['low'] <= $car['high']) 
    || ($search['high'] >= $car['low'] && $search['high'] <= $car['high']);
```

See below test program [here](https://3v4l.org/MRdGR):

```
$car = ['low' => 1000, 'high' => 5000];

$search_positive_tests = [
    ['low' => 999, 'high' => 1001],
    ['low' => 1001, 'high' => 4999],
    ['low' => 4999, 'high' => 5001]
];

$search_negative_tests = [
    ['low' => 998, 'high' => 999],
    ['low' => 5001, 'high' => 6000]
];

function is_match($car, $search)
{
    return
        ($search['low'] >= $car['low'] && $search['low'] <= $car['high']) 
        || ($search['high'] >= $car['low'] && $search['high'] <= $car['high']);
}


foreach ( $search_positive_tests as $search )
{
    if ( !is_match($car, $search) )
        throw new Exception('(' . $car['low'] . ' => ' . $car['high'] . ') should have matched (' . $search['low'] . ' => ' . $search['high'] . ')');
}

foreach ( $search_negative_tests as $search )
{
    if ( is_match($car, $search) )
        throw new Exception($car['low'] . ' => ' . $car['high'] . ' should not have matched (' . $search['low'] . ' => ' . $search['high'] . ')');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like the following should do the trick:

```
$userInputMin = 600;
$userInputMax = 2300;

function findCarWithinRange($lower, $upper) {
  $lowerLimit = 0;
  $upperLimit = 999999;
  $lower = max($lower, $lowerLimit);
  $upper = min($upper, $upperLimit);
  $cars = ['a' => 500, 'b' => 1000, 'c' => 1500, 'd' => 2000, 'f' => 2500];

  $carsWithinRange = array();

  foreach ($cars as $key => $value) {
      if ($value >= $lower && $value <= $upper) {
          $carsWithinRange[$key] = $value;
      }
  }

  return $carsWithinRange;
}

print_r(findCarWithinRange($userInputMin, $userInputMax));
// output: Array ( [b] => 1000 [c] => 1500 [d] => 2000 )
```